# Find anagrams from a file

Tags: java, interview-questions, javafx

The program reads words line by line from a file. It finds anagram groups and prints them in new line. Except for the GUI class, the anagram class takes 2ms.

I would like to be criticized in detail readability, correctness, efficiency, error handling and name convention.

And for potential question: if a data set is much larger, how will my application cope with it?

```
public class Anagram{

        List<List<String>> anagramGroupList = null;

        public List<List<String>> findAnagrams(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {

            try {
                // Open the file
                FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                Map<String, List<String>> anagramMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
                String word;

                // Read File Line By Line
                while ((word = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Sort characters of word
                    String sortedWord = sorting(word);

                    /*
                     * Use sorted word as a key for map
                     * If map contains key, add the list
                     * If not, create a new anagram list and add list with key
                     */
                    if (!anagramMap.containsKey(sortedWord))
                        anagramMap.put(sortedWord, new ArrayList<String>());

                    anagramMap.get(sortedWord).add(word);
                }

                anagramGroupList = new ArrayList<List<String>>(anagramMap.values());

                bufferedReader.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return anagramGroupList;

        }

        // Sort alphabetically characters of given word
        private static String sorting(String word) {
            char[] sortedChars = word.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(sortedChars);
            return new String(sortedChars);
        }
    }
```

Application class:

```
public class AnagramFinder extends Application {

    private TextArea textArea;
    private static final String titleTxt = "Find Anagrams";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Application.launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage applicationStage) {

        applicationStage.setTitle(titleTxt);

        // Window label
        Label appLabel = new Label("Select Anagram File");
        appLabel.setTextFill(Color.DARKBLUE);
        appLabel.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 24));
        HBox hBox = new HBox();
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        hBox.getChildren().add(appLabel);

        // Buttons
        Button fileChooserButton = new Button("Choose a file...");
        fileChooserButton.setOnAction(new SingleFcButtonListener());
        HBox buttonHBox = new HBox(10);
        buttonHBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        buttonHBox.getChildren().addAll(fileChooserButton);

        // Text area in a scroll pane and label
        Label textAreaLabel = new Label("Findings Anagrams:");
        textAreaLabel.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.SEMI_BOLD, 15));
        textArea = new TextArea();
        textArea.setWrapText(true);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        ScrollPane scroll = new ScrollPane();
        scroll.setContent(textArea);
        scroll.setFitToWidth(true);
        scroll.setFitToHeight(true);
        scroll.setPrefHeight(250);
        scroll.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        scroll.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);

        // Vbox
        VBox vbox = new VBox(15);
        vbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15));
        vbox.getChildren().addAll(hBox, buttonHBox, textAreaLabel, scroll);

        // Scene
        Scene appScene = new Scene(vbox, 750, 500);
        applicationStage.setScene(appScene);
        applicationStage.show();

    }

    private class SingleFcButtonListener implements EventHandler<ActionEvent> {

        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            textArea.clear();
            fileChooser();
        }
    }

    private void fileChooser() {

        FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
        File selectedFile = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

        if (selectedFile != null) {

            try {

                Anagram anagram = new Anagram();

                List<List<String>> anagramGroupList = anagram.findAnagrams(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());

                // Retrieves anagram groups from list
                for (List<String> anagramList : anagramGroupList) {
                    if (anagramList.size() > 1) {
                        for (String angrm : anagramList) {
                            textArea.appendText(angrm + " ");
                        }
                        textArea.appendText("\n");
                    }

                }

            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            textArea.appendText("File Selection Cancelled!!!");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in another post, it's better to extract the code that reads from the file into a separate class, and keep the original class to find the anagram groups. Applying the [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle will not only improve your readability, but will also improve your design in various ways.

Here are a few general comments:

- Variable naming is generally nice and clear. A couple of minor things are:

  - Maybe rename the class to `AnagramFinder` or `Anagrams`.
  - `sorting` could better be named as `sorted` or `getSorted`. You might also consider `getSignature` to hide the implementation detail of how the key is created.
- There is no reason for `anagramGroupList` to be an instance variable. Generally variables should be declared as close as possible to where they are used.
- If you can use an external library, consider using [Guava's Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html). It's similar to the normal `Map`, but each key could be associated with multiple values. So your definition of `anagramMap` could be `Multimap<String, String>`
- If Java8 is an option, you could make the code much cleaner by using streams. Also as a bonus, they are easily parallelizable, which could probably help if the dataset is too big. Here is the anagrams part rewritten with streams:

  ```
  class AnagramFinder {

    public static Map<String, List<String>> findAnagrams(List<String> words) {
      return words.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AnagramFinder::sorted));
    }

    private static String sorted(String word) {
      char[] sortedChars = word.toCharArray();
      Arrays.sort(sortedChars);
      return new String(sortedChars);
    }
  }
  ```
- I wouldn't worry much about optimization or performance for this simple program. You are only using around twice the input size, it's probably not worth it to optimize more than that.

Comment: While exracting file operations from Anagram class, which one is more appropriate, creating a new class like AnagramImpl or handle that oprations in Application class.

Comment: I think extracting a new class would be more appropriate. The new class doesn't need to know about anagrams at all, it could be something like WordFileReader, that way it could be used in different applications and not only for anagrams.

Answer (score 3):

The method findAnagrams dealing with filePaths, InputStreams and FileNotFoundException is a code smell for me.  I expect a method with the name findAnagrams to work with words.

Actually, your Anagram class dealing with Files, InputStreams etc, breaks the SRP.  You should extract a class out of the Anagram class that handles the IO responsibility.  The separation makes the classes simpler and more flexible to change.